# I can not update or upgrade from 11.10. How can I troubleshoot this?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, update-manager

When I try to update or upgrade my Ubuntu 11.10 installation through either update manager or the terminal I get a connection error.  How can I troubleshoot this?

---

```
Err us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-updates/main firefox amd64 12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1 Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80] 
Err security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security/main firefox amd64 12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1 Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80] 
Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/… Connection failed [IP:91.189.92.151 80] 
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing
```

Comment: Please can you post the wording of the error? Also post output of this command typed into a treminal. dpkg -l |grep dpkg

Comment: ii  dpkg                                   1.16.0.3ubuntu5.1                       Debian package management system

Comment: Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main firefox amd64 12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main firefox amd64 12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Are you connecting to the Internet through a proxy?

Comment: Well am using a mobile usb modem. However, i have been using this all the while and have been able to update my ubuntu until recently. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I just checked the IP listed in your error message and it is offline. What company is the mobile USB trying to connect to??

Comment: MTN. but if i put the ip in my firefox browser am able to reach the site

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to reach remote server on the internet using IP address, but not by domain name, then most likely you need to update your DNS servers:

1. Edit /etc/resolv.conf:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
2. If any nameserver lines appear, write down the IP addresses for future reference.
   Replace the nameserver lines with, or add, the following lines:

   *For IPv4:*

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
   ```

   *For IPv6:*

   ```
   nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
   nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
   ```
3. Save and exit.
4. Restart any Internet clients you are using.
5. Test that your setup is working correctly:

   ```
   ping google.com
   ```

Reference: [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)

Comment: Dont know what happened, i tried again this morning without going through the proposed solution but its working. Updating through the terminal though